# Having trouble overriding the document object in JavaScript

Tags: javascript, overriding

I'm having a spot of trouble overriding the `document` object for my JavaScript.

```
function myFunction(document) {
    [code]
}
```

works fine. But

```
function myFunction(newDocument) {
    document=newDocument
    [code]
}
```

does not. So far I'm managing fine using functions with the former method, but I'd rather just override the document object once and forget about it. If anyone could show me the proper way to globally override the document object, I'd appreciate it.

Comment: Do you mean "override"? Read the description of the overloading tag and see if it describes what you want.

Comment: Why do you want to override the document object? What are you trying to achieve by doing so?

Comment: I don't think you can override the document object like that. If you did it would render your script out of context, because the script is running under the replaced document.

Comment: To be clear: My intention is to replace the actual `document` object itself with a custom object of my own. I am doing this because it allows me to quickly repurpose a large amount of preexisting code.

Answer (score 2):

I'm going to go out-on-a-limb and say this cannot be done, nor should it be done.

If you replace the current `document` object (that your `script` is running under) than wouldn't your script go out of scope/context?

I made a fiddle [(http://jsfiddle.net/V3Rsh/)](http://jsfiddle.net/V3Rsh/) that suggests this cannot be done (at least in Firefox 20). If you look at the console it reports the same URL before and after the `document` assignment. But if you debug and put a breakpoint on the first `console.log()` and run the document = newDocument() line manually in the console you will see a `document` object created that has the 'about:blank" URL. But the subsequent call to `console.log()` does NOT reflect that.

Comment: Well, that's why I originally used the term "overloading" instead. I don't need the actual `document` object and its attendant scope, etc. to disappear. I just need that any code mentioning `document` references my "document" instead of the actual document object. Like I said, so far the method where I have a function argument with the name "document" works fine. Similarly, creating a document `var` works too.

Comment: It's a little crufty, but I guess I can get it to work if I fiddle enough with vars and scope.

Comment: @TomSanders are you using this for unit testing? If so, you can run your code in nodejs and get rid of the naming issue altogether